# Cassandra type error

Tags: java, cassandra

```
    Row row = DataSession._getSession().execute("select count (*) from sivri_service.bronzelist").one();
    int expected = row.getVarint("count").intValue();
```

I am attempting to get the count from a table, but I cannot seem to get past this exception:
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidTypeException: Column count is of type bigint

Answer (score 14):

"Column count is of type bigint"

Based on this chart which maps [CQL3 data types to Java types](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cql_data_types_c.html#ref-cql-data-types__ref-COMM-192), you'll want to get that value as a `long`, instead.

```
long expected = row.getLong("count");
```

Note: I am making a (educated) guess that you are using Java.  Next time, please indicate this in your question to remove any doubt.

Comment: Thanks.  I will remember to indicate java

Comment: This is the correct answer. It seems the error message is incorrect. Count is a long.

Comment: They above link isn't working any more. Probably this one is the best replacement targeting the actual documentation: http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cql_data_types_c.html#ref-cql-data-types__ref-COMM-192

Comment: @GreenTurtle Thanks for looking up the new link!  Just fixed it.